# OpenVPN use clients internet connection not tunnel for general web

Tags: openvpn, centos6

I have a VPN setup for Yealink phones and currently 100% of all traffic goes through it when it is enabled. I am now trying to setup a backup server which is accessible at 100.##.#.##. I need the VPN to only apply to requests that use 10.8.*.* and all other requests avoid the vpn entirely (Or is it possible to only allow a single IP), the idea behind this is the main server goes down so it cannot route traffic.

Everything is using Linux or Centos no windows.

```
Server.conf
local 162.0.0.0
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
management localhost 7505
verb 4
```

---

```
Client.cnf
remote servername.com 1194 udp
client
setenv SERVER_POLL_TIMEOUT 4
nobind
dev tun
dev-type tun
remote-cert-tls server
reneg-sec 604800
sndbuf 100000
rcvbuf 100000
auth-retry nointeract
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/client.crt
key keys/client.key
```

So I need all 10.8.*.* requests to use the VPN and everything that isn't 10.8.*.* to bypass the VPN and access the internet normally. This is for if the VPN server shuts down and devices need to use the backup server.

What should I change? I have tried various failed attempts at using route-nopull and a couple other changes with no effect.

Edit 1: `ip r` info

Without VPN:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.143  metric 9
```

With VPN:

```
default via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto static 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.1 
10.8.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto static 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
122.12.6.94 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.143  metric 9
```

Comment: The configuration you've given does not send all traffic through the VPN, only traffic for 10.8.0.0/16. Have you omitted something? Check the `ccd` directory for instance.

Comment: This is the entire Server/Client config. I am testing this on Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon using the default network manager.

The CCD directory has 2 blank files. No other config files exist. 

Its possible its not sending traffic to the VPN but I can't even ping 8.8.8.8 when I have the VPN enabled so something is not working.

Comment: While I had the VPN on I pinged 8.8.8.8 from my ethernet connected interface and it gave me `From 192.168.1.143 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable`.  While my VPN was on I pinged 8.8.8.8 from my VPN tunnel interface then not selecting any interface and both gave me `18 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 17115ms` and both have the same look in the terminal. So it looks to me like its using the Tunnel by default.

Comment: Per the posted routing tables.  Either the config you posted is incomplete, or something is passing a cli option to the client or server to redirect the default gateway.  Unrelated, I do suggest you consider switching over to `topology subnet` instead of the net30.  Just add that option on the server.

Comment: It seems that it wasn't my configs doing that it was the VPN client on Mint/Ubuntu. Also that topology subnet did fix one of the inconsistencies I was having on our testing devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Mint and Ubuntu both use the NetworkManager GUI as noted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/254031/change-openvpn-clients-default-route

It seems that by default NetworkManager will force all traffic to go through the VPN by default even if it is not set in any configs. I just had to go into the VPN I added -> IPV4 -> Scroll to the bottom and check "use this connection only for resources on its network". Boom I could access everything on the internet from my connection.

[use this connection only for resources on its network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jitsj.png)

Really unexpected behavior though.

Comment: Yeah I agree. You never mentioned using NetworkManager and your question suggested that you were not. But this is a thing that NM is well known to do, and if you had mentioned it we would have been able to identify it immediately. In future, if you have questions, please take the time to ensure that all relevant details are included. You'll get better answers faster.

Comment: I said I was on linux mint 17.3 cinnamon. That is the default and I didn't even know the name of it till I found that answer.